# Elasticsearch regexp on query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following query which works great:

```
query: {
  multi_match: {
   fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "sku"],
   query: query,
   type: "cross_fields",
   operator: "and"
}
```

However, I'd like to have the incoming `query` get rid of non-alphanumeric characters, using this regex:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9\ @\.]
```

Is there a way to have Elasticsearch filter the incoming `query` for that regex for all fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a different analyzer for search during query construction.

```
query: {
  multi_match: {
   fields: ["first_name", "last_name", "email", "sku"],
   query: query,
   type: "cross_fields",
   operator: "and",
   analyzer: "your-custom-analyzer"
}
```

You have to provide the definition of "your-custom-analyzer" in the mapping. The analyzer definition can use the [pattern replace filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/analysis-pattern-replace-charfilter.html) to meet your requirement.

Comment: This works - thank you! Thank you very much. However, it seems that I have to specify `index_analyzer` on each mapping for it to work as well as have it on the query. Is this the behavior?

Comment: Yes if you have specific need for a custom analyzer. You don't have to if you are ok with "standard analyzer". But it depends on your needs. If you don't specify any analyzer in the mapping be default the "standard analyzer" will be considered for for both indexing and searching. Now if you specify "your-custom-analyzer" for search query then "standard analyzer" will be used for indexing and "your-custom-analyzer" will be used for searching.

Comment: Okay thank you for the clarification. I just have one question regarding this which has confused me. I had to mention `index_analyzer: your-custom-analyzer' on the mapping, as well as `analyzer: your-custom-analyzer` on the query search. If I did not have `index_analyzer: your-custom-analyzer' on the mapping, then the search did not work either. Odd... Perhaps it's because of it tokenizing with the illegal characters in there?

Comment: You are right. As I had mentioned earlier if you don't  specify analyzer, the "standard analyzer" will used while indexing which tokenizes by special characters with certain conditions. So the best approach is to define correct analyzers for your fields in the mapping itself. And defining mapping is generally a one time process so it should not cause much inconvenience.